# In ES6, how can I splice the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, prototype-chain

If I have this code:

```
class Z           { foo () {return 'from Z';} }

class A           { foo () {return 'from A';} }
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }

var c = new C();
```

I know I can get the prototype chain this way:

```
consonle.log(c.foo());
var obj = c;

while(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) {
  obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  console.log(obj);
}

// Puts out:
// from A
// C {}
// B {}
// A {}
// {}
```

How can I insert an instance of Z into the prototype chain between the `A {}` and `B {}` such that the same script puts out the following?

```
// from Z
// C {}
// B {}
// Z {}
// A {}
// {}
```

**Update**

To clarify, I'd like to update the prototype chain such that NEW INSTANCES of C can take advantage of Z's `.foo()` method.

**Update 2**

Ok, I can accept that this isn't possible.  How can I splice a particular instance of Z into the prototype chain of a particular instance of C?

Comment: Since `Z` doesn't inherit from `A`, the chain would have to stop there. Well, you probably *could* get that to work somehow, but: You can *mixin* arbitrary methods into existing prototypes, e.g. `B.prototype.foo = Z.prototype.foo`; perhaps that's rather what you're looking for?

Comment: You have XY problem. The actual solution depends on what you need. There could be an array of hooks or something else.

Comment: @estus I have a class (A) that may or may not extend other classes.  I want an instance of A to assume that it can call methods from `this` from another class.

Comment: A more concrete explanation could help. Not A and B. Because it depends on particular case. There's a good chance that you're misusing inheritance, so another approach could help.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to update the prototype chain such that NEW INSTANCES of C can take advantage of Z

That's not possible. If you want to insert `Z` as the prototype of `B`, then *everything* that inherits from `B` will also get `Z` properties. That includes all `B` and old `C` instances.

To distinguish them and not affect the old instances, you would need to make a brand new `B` and `C`.

If you still want to do it, here's how:

```
class A           { foo () {return 'from A';} }
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }

// Oops, B should inherit from Z not A:

class Z extends A { foo () {return 'from Z';} }
Object.setPrototypeOf(B, Z);
Object.setPrototypeOf(B.prototype, Z.prototype);

var c = new C();
```

Comment: Ok, I can accept that.  How can I splice a particular instance of Z into the prototype chain of a particular instance of C?

Comment: One object has only one prototype, not a complete list of all its prototypes. These links form a chain - and when multiple objects reference the same prototype, they share that part of the chain. Also notice that you never should inherit from an instance (an object that keeps its own state). Prototype objects should be stateless, exactly because they affect multiple objects that inherit from them. That said, to answer the question how to mess with prototypes, there's [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

Comment: Yeah, I get that... that's why I wanted to know how to traverse the chain and insert something into it...